# Serving Up PDF File Download Fails in IE7/8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, zend-framework, http-headers, file-handling

I am using Zend and have some files outside of the webroot that I would like to be able to serve up.  I have tried two approaches, both of which work in all browsers except for versions of IE 8 or lower.

The two (working) approaches that I have tried are the following:

```
  // Approach #1
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  header("Pragma: ");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
  readfile($file);      

  // Approach #2
  $this->getResponse()
   ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=$filename")
  ->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pdf');
  fpassthru($file);
```

Like I said, both approaches work in modern browsers (even IE9) but not in older versions of IE.  The error I am getting is the following: http://cl.ly/image/1G3x370b1s09

I have looked into several posts on this topic and tried more different combinations of headers than I can even count.  Is there a more bulletproof way of handling this functionality that wont cause issues with older browsers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've fought with this before and I think it stems from caching headers.

There's three: `Expires`, `Cache-Control` (HTTP 1.1), and `Pragma` (HTTP 1.0). My experience has been the older versions of IE like to see all three of these headers. Try using the following prior to any other headers and content you send:

```
header("Cache-control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: -1");
```

This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067) from Microsoft goes in to more discussion about the caching headers.

This is what I have done in the past to get it to work:

```
$file = $fileInfo->openFile('r');
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file->getFilename().'"');
print $file->fpassthru()
```

Comment: Unfortunately even with those tweaks (and several other similar changes) IE8 still will not play nicely.  I think it may be time to try a completely different approach.

Comment: I went and dug up what I've used in the past and modified my answer. Not sure if it gives you the desired behavior, but it's what we're using in production now.

Comment: Are you accessing via SSL by any chance?

Comment: kulishch: I am using HTTPS.

Comment: AH HA! I think [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q316431&) applies.

Comment: kulishch: Thank you very much for the link!  Unfortunately still no luck, I am pulling my hair out over this one.

Comment: Grrr! I know how you feel. We've dealt with it multiple times without ever knowing what we truly did to make it work, just that what did do worked.

Answer (score 0):

Against my will I gave up on trying to fight with headers and completely changed the way I am handling file downloads.  When a user requests a file now, it is temporarily hashed, copied to an area that the web-server can see, the user is redirect to that file and once they leave the download area the file is deleted.  If they go inactive the file is deleted automatically at a set interval.

Thank you for all of the input kulishch and how ironic is it that you are from Minnesota as well!?  Happy Holidays!

-- Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

Follwing the advice at http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q316431&, these headers worked for me:

```
header("Cache-control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: -1");
```

I always get caught out by this! :(